# Unclear behavior of .text Content

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I was making some practice to change the content of a `<p>` element using the .textContent and firstly I assigned the whole element to a let variable

```
let player1Score_El = document.getElementById ("score--0").textContent = 0;
```

The issue comes later when I need to change the content inside a function using another variable that carry a number value when clicking a button with `addEventListener`:

```
player1Score_El.textContent = score;
```

then in console I get the error message:

> script.js:23 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'textContent' on number '0'
> at HTMLButtonElement.holdFunc (script.js:23)

I solved the issue by removing the `.textContent = 0;` from the `player1Score_El` variable declaration, and then reassigning the content again to the variable in global scope with 0 value.

Ok well. I will insert the code with the issue and the code after I fixed it.

Here the code with issue:

```
'use strict';
//setting the needed variables;
let score = 0;
let currentScore = 0;
let currentScore_0El = document.getElementById ("current--0");
let player1Score_El = document.getElementById ("score--0").textContent = 0;
let diceImg = document.querySelector (".dice");


//Setting roll dice button functionl;
const rollDiceFunc = function () {
const diceRoll = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
currentScore += diceRoll;
currentScore_0El.textContent = currentScore;
diceImg.src = `dice-${diceRoll}.png`;
}
document.querySelector (".btn--roll").addEventListener("click",rollDiceFunc);

// Implementing Hold button function;
const holdFunc = function () {
  
  score = score + currentScore;
  player1Score_El.textContent = score;
  // console.log(player1Score_El);
  
  currentScore = 0;
  currentScore_0El.textContent = currentScore;
}
document.querySelector (".btn--hold").addEventListener ("click", holdFunc);
```

and here is the code after fixing the issue:

```
'use strict';
//setting the needed variables;
let score = 0;
let currentScore = 0;
let currentScore_0El = document.getElementById ("current--0");
let player1Score_El = document.getElementById ("score--0");
let diceImg = document.querySelector (".dice");

 player1Score_El.textContent = 0;

//Setting roll dice button functionl;
const rollDiceFunc = function () {
const diceRoll = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
currentScore += diceRoll;
currentScore_0El.textContent = currentScore;
diceImg.src = `dice-${diceRoll}.png`;
}
document.querySelector (".btn--roll").addEventListener("click",rollDiceFunc);

// Implementing Hold button function;
const holdFunc = function () {
  
  score = score + currentScore;
  player1Score_El.textContent = score;
  // console.log(player1Score_El);
  
  currentScore = 0;
  currentScore_0El.textContent = currentScore;
}
document.querySelector (".btn--hold").addEventListener ("click", holdFunc);
```

What I need to understand why in variable declaration it doesn't work and when I reassign the value of the `player1Score_El` variable in another line then it worked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=` evaluates to the value assigned to it. That is:

```
leftHandExpression1 = leftHandExpression2 = someExpression
// equivalent to
leftHandExpression1 = (leftHandExpression2 = someExpression)
// equivalent to
leftHandExpression2 = someExpression;
leftHandExpression1 = someExpression; // assuming no side-effects
```

In your code, you're assigning 0 to the text content, so that's what gets assigned to `player1Score_El`. Separating it out so there aren't chained `=`s fixes the problem because then `player1Score_El` is an actual element, not the 0.

I'd recommend never chaining `=`s in a single statement - it's confusing to read and is very often a typo or mistake.

Comment: Can you please confirm my understanding based on your comment?
I understood that when declaring a variable it will then treat every = as a new assigned value - in plain English: let varName = will equal to value1 which equals = to value 2 and will take value 2 as final declaration which in my case is 0. and 0 value will make the element gone at all. yeah it makes sense if like that. is that correct?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to by value1 and value2. Assignments can be evaluated as expressions, and `=` evaluates right-to-left. So `a = b = c` first does `b = c`. That expression evaluates to `c`. Next it does `a = c`.